# PWA with Background Sync, How to handle errors appears during the request to the server when the internet is available?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, background-sync

I am learning PWA (Progressive Web App). I am using Background Sync for offline operations and actions. So when the internet is back service worker perform that operations to the server.

My question is how to handle errors which we got at the time of server request in back sync. What is the best approach to handle this scenario ?

Comment: Can you add the errors you are seeing and where you are seeing them?

Comment: I am not having any errors now. but how can I handle error ? Like we use try catch for javascript. How can I handle error scenario in this ?

Comment: Oh Ok. Once you get some errors in your PWA you can post your question/error here with some of your code and someone can help you with it.

Comment: @Mathias what is your point ??